# Furstenberg-Zimmer theorem: non-invertible systems

Tags: ds.dynamical-systems, ergodic-theory, reference-request

### Questions

1. Is there a version of the Furstenberg-Zimmer Theorem for
   non-invertible measure preserving systems?
2. Where can I find it?
3. What is the precise statement?

### Background

In many works that reference the Furstenberg-Zimmer Theorem,
the theorem itself is not stated.
Authors usually cite the works of Furstenberg
(*The structure of distal flows*
and/or
*Ergodic behavior of diagonal measures and a
theorem of Szemerédi on arithmetic progressions*)
and Zimmer
([*Extensions of ergodic group actions*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/illinois-journal-of-mathematics/volume-20/issue-3/Extensions-of-ergodic-group-actions/10.1215/ijm/1256049780.full)
and/or
[*Extensions of ergodic actions and generalized discrete spectrum*](https://projecteuclid.org/journals/bulletin-of-the-american-mathematical-society-new-series/volume-81/issue-3.P1/Extensions-of-ergodic-actions-and-generalized-discrete-spectrum/bams/1183536891.full)).
The point is that in many places, the theorem is being used
for non-invertible systems.
This happens, for instance in
[On Li-Yorke Pairs](https://www.imath.kiev.ua/%7Eskolyada/LY.pdf),
where the systems are assumed to be surjective, but not
necessarily invertible.
In this paper, for the proof of Theorem 2.1, the authors
use Furstenber-Zimmer Theorem.

As far as I understood, Zimmer's work deals with
*group actions*.
That is, invertible systems.
And for Furstenberg's *Ergodic behaviour of diagonal measures [...]*,
he deals with *regular measure preserving systems*.

Unfortunately, Furstenberg and Zimmer (obviously) did not call their result
*the Furstenberg-Zimmer Theorem*.
In fact, it seems to me that
Furstenberg didn't even call it a *theorem*. :-P

I could find a precise statement of the theorem
for the invertible case at a
[Terry Tao's post](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/03/05/254a-lecture-15-the-furstenberg-zimmer-structure-theorem-and-the-furstenberg-recurrence-theorem/).
But I could not find any precise statement for the non-invertible case.

Comment: Not explicitly calling it a theorem is not a crime :) They may have called it a proposition, and others promoted it to a theorem. Or even a lemma... But I like this question. 

Comment: Thank you for your comment, David.
Furstenberg's paper is too difficult for me.
It is possible I am totally wrong, but what I found closer to the theorem was a comment after definition 8.4. He says that if you _follow_ the proof of Theorem 8.3 you can define a _distal series_ which can also be defined transfinitely, allowing one to reach at a _maximal distal factor_. Furstenberg continues: _These notions were referred to in the Introduction, but we shall not actually make use of them in the sequel_.

Comment: @David: Only now I understood that I sounded like complaining about Furstenberg. I am not. He was looking for something else. But since it is not stated as a theorem in his paper, I am complaining about authors that say: _according to Furstenberg Theorem (see blah blah)_ without giving a reference to where it is stated. :-(

Comment: @Andre,I didn't see where Tao assumed that T is invertible, anyways,a good recent ref. would be Manfred's book-Chapter 7,and maybe even Furstenberg's book.
For every system there's a compact (Borel, standrad, whatever kind of space you like) extension making it bi-invarient (see Manfred's book) and you usually can analyze this situation and then project it down to the original system without too much of a trouble (because the fibers are compact). For example in the SZ theorem, you can basically work with one-sided shift and not two-sided, this is enough for proving SZ by Furstenberg's method.

Comment: @Asaf: Tao assumes it in Lecture 1: http://terrytao.wordpress.com/2008/01/08/254a-lecture-1-overview/  
For the reference you pointed (Manfred), I think this is exactly what I needed. I didn't know about this book. If I may, I'd like to suggest you to post it as an answer. :-)  
Manfred's book is what I should be reading!!  
Thank you very very much!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Posted as requested - consult the book by Manfred Einsiedler and Tom Ward - "Ergodic Theory with a view towards number theory" - published in GTM, especially in ch 7.

Comment: Thank you very much, Asaf!  
This is my new canonical reference for ergodic theory. I am ordering this book.  
I had a pick, and what I really needed was Theorem 7.21. It is stated for not necessarily invertible "Borel Probability Spaces" (Definition 5.13).